# MySQL get 80 rows every day

Tags: php, mysql

I have 7500 rows in the table, and i have 4 users, and the users editing the 80 records to save on same the table, How i can distribution for all users 80 rows every day (And tomorrow is distributed new 80 records from the table to users)

My code to get data (**Last updated for today and yesterday**)

Today:

```
SELECT * FROM  invoices WHERE DATE('ModifiedTime')=CURDATE()
```

Yesterday:

```
SELECT * FROM  invoices WHERE DATE('ModifiedTime')=(CURDATE()-1)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? How are they assigned to users? Do you want 80 random records for each user? Do they need to be 80 different records each? Also what have you tried so far? You need to make an effort in solving this yourself.

Comment: no not random، the user edit  80 records every day, and tomorrow i need to show 80 records not edited from any users

Comment: I think you need the `<` operator, so you get all records that have not been edited in the past day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[LIMIT](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp)** statment

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 80 ORDER BY Orders.ID";
```

This will select the first 80 records

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders LIMIT 80, 80 ORDER BY Orders.ID";
```

This will select the record from number 80 to number 160

Comment: Please don't just link your answer, links break over time. Copy any appropriate text into your answer.

Comment: LIMIT without an ORDER BY clause is fairly meaningless. Also, whatever the OP's problem, this is not a very practical solution.

Comment: @Strawberry I omitted it because it was an example, but you are right so I updated the answer!

Comment: Assa, SQL queries need to adhere to a specific syntax. This is not it. Without an ORDER BY clause, a SELECT *may* return 'the first 80 records' but there is no technical requirement for it to do so. An ORDER BY clause is therefore essential, and it comes before the LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would include a table (let's call it `user_invoices`) linking records in the invoice table to records in the users table. This way you could assign records to users, and track the editing process - ie: have the records been edited

This would involve querying the invoices table for a set of records for each user, and adding the invoice record ID and the user's userID to the `user_invoices`.